# Computing $L$-rank (constructible universe)

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

I posted this question on Math StackExchange but did not get a full answer. I hope it's not a problem if I ask again here.

Is there a way to compute explicitly the $L$−rank $\rho(\bigcup x)$ of $\bigcup x$ in terms of $\rho(x)$? I know it's necessarily $\rho(\bigcup x)\leq\rho(x)$ and that both $\rho(\bigcup x)<\rho(x)$ and $\rho(\bigcup x)=\rho(x)$ can hold, but what else can be said, maybe distinguishing between $\rho(x)$ limit ordinal and successor ordinal? For example, is it possible that equality holds if $\rho(x)$ is a successor ordinal? If so, could you give an example?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565208/l-rank-kunen-exercise

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to compute explicitly $\rho(\bigcup x)$ in terms of $\rho(x)$, in any meaningful fashion: e.g. (working in $L$) for arbitrarily large countable $\alpha$ there are reals $x\subseteq \omega$ with $\rho(x)$ a limit or successor greater than $\alpha$ but with $\rho(\bigcup x) =\omega$ of course.  (Because for arbitrarily large such $\alpha$ there is a new real $x$ definable over $L_\alpha$. If $\alpha$ is not a successor, then there will always be a new real definable over $L_{\alpha +1 } $ too; for example the real that codes $L_\alpha$; similarly if $\alpha$ is not a limit there will in any case be a new real definable over $L_{\alpha + \omega}$.) Thus the gap between the two ranks under either assumption can be as wide as it could conceivably be.

If $\rho(x)=\gamma+1$ then $\rho(\bigcup x)= \rho(x)$ can happen. Work in $L$: Suppose $x\subseteq \omega$ has $\rho(x)=\gamma +1$.  Let $y = \{ \{u\} \mid u \in x \}$. Then $\rho(y)\leq\gamma +1 $;  $\rho(\bigcup y) =\rho(x)$, but $\rho(y)\leq\gamma$ would imply that $\rho(x)\leq\gamma$.

Comment: Actually this is not totally correct.  It's true that new reals are constructed arbitrarily high, but surprisingly, there are also arbitrarily long gaps where no new reals appear.  Let $\alpha < \omega_1$ be arbitrary, and let $\omega_1 > \beta > \alpha$ be such that there is an elementary $j : L_\beta \to L_{\omega_2}$ with $cr(j) = \gamma \geq \alpha$.  Then for all $\delta < \gamma$, $L_{\omega_2} \models$ "There are no new reals constructed between $\omega_1$ and $\omega_1 + \delta$."  By elementarity and absoluteness, there are no new reals added between $\gamma$ and $\gamma + \delta$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you give me an explanation for your last statement? I can't see why equality can't hold if $\rho(x)=\gamma+1$.

Comment: @Monroe: which part of my answer is incorrect?

Comment: It seems like you said if $\alpha$ is a countable limit, then a new real appears in $L_{\alpha+1}$.

Comment: Or rather $L_{\alpha+2}$.

Comment: @Monroe: I was discussing in the parenthetical remark ``such $\alpha$'' with a new real appearing definably over $L_\alpha$. Then one will also appear over $L_{\alpha +1}$, ... , $L_{\alpha+\omega}$...   :)

Comment: Oh I see, sorry.